# how to use built-in content type negotiation and just get access to the decision

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, content-negotiation

I wanted to take advantage of built-in content negotiator and just get access to decision what formatter is going to be used.  I don't want to use Request.Headers.Accept and check for whether it is json or xml content type because there lot of things are involved in that decision.  Is there a way I can check at controller level or override any class that tells me what formatter going to be used OR what request content type is?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can run conneg manually:

```
var conneg = Configuration.Services.GetContentNegotiator();
        var connegResult = conneg.Negotiate(
            typeof(YOUR_TYPE), Request, Configuration.Formatters
        );
```

And use the output whichever way you want:

```
//the valid media type
var mediaType = connegResult.MediaType;
//do stuff

//the relevant formatter
var formatter = connegResult.Formatter;
//do stuff
```

Comment: Thanks Filip.  Why can't I get Services object reference in Configuration?  I don't see it in intellisense.

Comment: Are you using Web API RC? Services is a public property of System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration

Comment: I did installed ASP.NET MVC 4.  ASP.NET Web API was part of that installation package.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see what is going on then install a TraceWriter and you will see what the conneg does.

A TraceWriter looks something like:

```
    public class TraceWriter : ITraceWriter {
        public bool IsEnabled(string category, TraceLevel level) {
            return true;
        }

        public void Trace(HttpRequestMessage request, string category, TraceLevel level, Action<TraceRecord> traceAction) {
            var rec = new TraceRecord(request, category, level);
            traceAction(rec);
            Log(rec);
        }

        private void Log(TraceRecord record) {
            Console.WriteLine(record.Message);
        }
    }
```

and is installed like this,

```
     config.Services.Replace(typeof(ITraceWriter), new TraceWriter());
```

If you want to manually invoke conneg then you can use,

```
     config.Services.GetContentNegotiator().Negotiate(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tugberk has a [blog](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/running-the-content-negotiation-conneg-manually-in-asp-net-web-api) on this. Have a look.

Comment: thanks.  I have tried that code but some how I can't get Servics object reference of Configuration.  I don't see them in intellisense even.  I am using ASP.NET MVC 4.